# Pull random 8 images from directory for my game using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Noobie here, Apologies if you find this question silly,

I have created a memory game with 8 default images. Now i want to access image directory to get random images for the game. The main logic of the game is written using Javascript and PHP. now i have created a new php file (random.php) to get random image from directory

the code I have used to retrieve a random image from directory :(random.php)

```
 <?php $dire="Annotated Dataset/";
 $images = glob($dire. '*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
 shuffle($images);
 $images=array_slice($images, 0, 8);
 foreach ($images as $key) {
 // code...
 $randomImage = array_pop($images);
 ?>
 <input type="image" src="<?=$randomImage;?>" alt="<?=$randomImage;?>" />
 <?php }?>
```

the game logic (game.js)

```
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8];
var lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
var lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;
var wait = false;
var matches = 0;
var numTries =0;
var moves = 0;
var counter = document.querySelector(".moves");
var finaltime=0;
var gamescore;
var totalscore;
//elements
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

//code
shuffle(numbers);
distributeNumbers();


for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var turnable = e.target.dataset.turnable;

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var turnable = e.target.dataset.turnable;


//first click
if (!wait && lastKnownButtonId == undefined && lastKnownButtonNumber == undefined && turnable == 'true') {
  e.target.dataset.turnable = 'false';

  e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

  lastKnownButtonId = e.target.id;
  lastKnownButtonNumber = e.target.dataset.number;

}
//second click
else if (!wait && lastKnownButtonId != undefined && lastKnownButtonNumber != undefined && turnable == 'true' && e.target.id != lastKnownButtonId) {
  e.target.dataset.turnable = 'false';

  e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(event.target.dataset.number);




  //match
  if (e.target.dataset.number == lastKnownButtonNumber) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#00FF7F';
    document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId).style.backgroundColor = '#00FF7F';

    lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
    lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;

    matches++;


    if (matches == 8) {

    showWinScreen();
    //clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    document.getElementById("finalMove").innerHTML = moves;


    }

  }

  //no match
  else {
    document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    wait = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      e.target.dataset.turnable = 'true';
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
      e.target.innerHTML = getgImage(0);


      var tempLastClickedButton = document.getElementById(lastKnownButtonId);

      tempLastClickedButton.dataset.turnable = 'true';
      tempLastClickedButton.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      tempLastClickedButton.innerHTML = getgImage(0);

      lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
      lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;
      wait = false;
    }, 1000);


  }

 }

});
}
function moveCounter(){
++moves;
//counter.innerHTML = moves;
}


 window.onload = function() {
  var timeoutHandle;
  function countdown(minutes, seconds) {
      function tick() {
          var timecounter = document.getElementById("timer");
          timecounter.innerHTML = minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
          seconds--;
          if (seconds >= 0) {
              timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
          } else {
              if (minutes >= 1) {

                  setTimeout(function () {
                      countdown(minutes - 1, 59);
                  }, 1000);
              }
          }
          if (seconds==0 && minutes ==0){

            alert("Game over");
            //reset();
          }
          if (matches==8){
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
            finaltime= (timecounter.innerHTML=seconds);
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML= finaltime;
            var totalscore = calcScore();
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML= totalscore;



          }
      }
      tick();
  }

  countdown(1, 00); }




 // showWinScreen();
 function calcScore(){
 var tilesbonus = (matches) * 20; // 20 points for each successful tile
 var timebonus = (finaltime) * 8;  // 8 points for each second
 var triesbonus = (30 - moves) * 10;  // (deduct) 10 points for each try
 if (tilesbonus <0) { tilesbonus = 0; }
 if (timebonus <0) { timebonus = 0; }
 if (triesbonus <0) { triesbonus = 0; }
 totalscore = tilesbonus + timebonus + triesbonus;
 return totalscore;
 }


 //functions
 function reset() {


 for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].innerHTML = getgImage(0);
 buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';

 document.querySelector('.win-container').style.display = 'none';

 document.getElementById("6").style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById("7").style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById("10").style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById("11").style.display = 'block';


 }
 lastKnownButtonId = undefined;
 lastKnownButtonNumber = undefined;
 wait = false;
 shuffle(numbers);
 distributeNumbers();
 matches = 0;
 moves = 0;
 counter.innerHTML = moves;
 //countdown=0;
 //m=timeArray[0];
 //s=0;

 }


function showWinScreen() {
document.querySelector('.win-container').style.display = 'flex';

document.getElementById("6").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("7").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("10").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("11").style.display = 'none';
}


function getgImage(number) {
switch (number) {
case '1':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion1.jpg">';
case '2':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion2.jpg">';
case '3':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion3.jpg">';
case '4':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion4.jpg">';
case '5':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion5.jpg">';
case '6':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion6.jpg">';
case '7':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion7.jpg">';
case '8':
  return '<img src="resources/fashion8.jpg">';
default:
  return '<img src="resources/logo.png">';

 }
 }
 function distributeNumbers() {
 for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].dataset.number = numbers[i];
 }
 }

 function shuffle(array) {
 var j, x, i;
 for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
 j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
 x = array[i];
 array[i] = array[j];
 array[j] = x;
 }
 return array; 
 }
```

php code for the game (game.php):

```
 <?php session_start();?>     
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
 <title>Javascript Memory Game</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <center><h4><div> Time :<span id ="timer"></span></div></h4></center>
  <main>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="1">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="2">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="3">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="4">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="5">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="6">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="7">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="8">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="9">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="10">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="11">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="12">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="13">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="14">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="15">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>
  <button data-turnable="true" data-number="0" id="16">
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="card back" />
  </button>


  <div class="win-container">
    <p><font size= "4"> You win!</font></p>
    <p><font size= "4">You made <span id=finalMove> </span> moves </font></p>
    <p><font size= "4">with <span id=seconds> </span> secs left </font></p>
    <p><font size= "4">Your score: <span id=score> </span></font></p>


    <button class="play-again" onclick="reset()">Play Again</button>
    <button id="sendscore" class="Go-on"><a href ="aftergame.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit;">Submit</a></button>
   </div>
  </main>

   <script defer="defer" src="game.js"></script>

  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </html>
```

I want to use the randomly generated pic from the PHP file and use it inside the switch case of the Javascript file. So it will be 8 random images. The image directory has more than 100 images.

I like to know how to proceed with this problem or if there are any alternatives to do. I dont have much experience with programming, so it will be much helpful if you help me with this problem.

Comment: Maybe not an option for you: In my opinion the easiest solution would be to have all the images be of the same filetype, and number them. 
If you know how many images there are, you can just pick any 8 random numbers in that range in your js. No need to bother with PHP at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to create a string that is used in your JS code.

Since your PHP code is executed server-side, and the JS is executed later on the client side, you can use PHP to write the variables you need in JS.

```
<?php
   $dir = './';
   $images = glob($dir. '*.{jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
   $quoted = join(',',array_map(function($image){
      return '"'.$image.'"';
   }, $images));
?>
<script>
  // here you move your PHP generated string into the JS realm
  const allImages = [<?= $quoted; ?>];

  // function to pick n amount of random images from the array.      
  const pickRandom = (arr,count) => {
    if(count < arr.length){
     console.error(`can not get ${count} items from array with length ${arr.length}`);
     return arr;
    }
    let _arr = [...arr];
    return[...Array(count)].map( ()=> _arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * _arr.length), 1)[0] );
  };

  console.log(pickRandom(allImages, 2));
</script>
```

Comment: i understood the idea you have said , could you help me with how to code it. the alternative solution you have presented makes really good logic, but could you shoe how to perform it as a code

Comment: i have edited my code above for random.php, now i am able to get random 8 images, but i want to add these images to the switch case, can you help me out.

Comment: I updated my answer. It's been a while since I did anything in PHP, so my head was stuck in REST API mode. As you can see, you can generate a string with PHP that you can use in your JS.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, since your JS and PHP files are separate from your HTML file, what I would recommend is an XMLHttpRequest from your JS file to your PHP file.

```
function getRandomImage() {
  var conn = new XMLHttpRequest(); //new xhr
  var result;                      //result input tag

  conn.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  //check if connection succeeded
      result = this.responseText; //assign response to result
    }
  }

  conn.open("GET","<path>/random.php",false); //open new connection
  conn.send(); //send

  return result; //something like '<input type="image" src="xxx.jpg" alt="xxx.jpg" />
}
```

Note that the last variable in `conn.open` is `false`. It's generally recommend to use `true` here as `false` is deprecated, but using `false` guarantees that the function will only return the result once the connection is completed and it actually has something to return. There are other ways to do this (look up Promises), but not any that I'm particularly well versed in.

**EDIT**

The rest of this answer is assuming that you decide to use XMLHttpRequest. JasperZelf's answer is also perfectly valid, and I still maintain that putting all code in a single file would be simpler overall. Disclaimers aside:

Since your `getgImage` function is designed to return the same set of images every time it's called, I'd recommend global variables to store the images once they're fetched from `random.php`. I'd put something like this near the top or bottom of your `game.js` file:

```
var image1 = getRandomImage();
var image2 = getRandomImage();
//...
var image7 = getRandomImage();
var image8 = getRandomImage();
```

And modify your `getgImage` function to look something like this:

```
function getgImage(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case '1':
      return image1;
    //...
    default:
      return '<img src="resources/logo.png">';
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but when i tried it with the switch case, the output is " <?=$randomImage;?>" for all the cases, i could not display the images , can you help me with this.

Comment: @Uviiii You'll have to post your full code somewhere for me to know exactly what's going on. I will say that putting all your php, js, and html in the same file like JasperZelf suggested is the simplest option.

Comment: i have edited and added the full code above, kindly help me with this problem

Comment: If you do: 
var image1 = getRandomImage();
var image2 = getRandomImage();
Image 1 and 2 can be the same image. 

You need to make sure that can not happen.